# Why is rsync slower within my SSD than to an external HDD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, rsync

I have partitioned my primary SSD, and mounted two partitions in my `/media` directory. `rsync` between these two partitions are slower than `rsync`-ing the same files to an external HDD, and I don't understand why. I have experienced this a lot, with different files and different external disks, but to have specific examples for this post, I used just two big video files. Commands and output are pasted below.

When transferring to an external HDD, the first ~10 GB transfers at about 400 MB/s, before slowing down to, and stabilizing at, about 100 MB/s (probably due to some buffer, I guess).
Transferring internally on the SSD, however, starts out at 40–60 MB/s, before slowly working up to a maximum of about 100 MB/s.

I have searched a lot, and other people usually experience slow transfers because of slow hardware, or tens of thousands of small files. However, this should be a reasonably fast SSD (faster than the external HDD anyway), and there are just two big files.

- `rsync` version 3.1.3
- Ubuntu 20.04
- All file systems are `ext4`

What could possibly be the reason for this, and is there anything I can do to fix this, or debug better?

Thank you!

Output from `lsblk`:

```
sda           8:0    0   4,6T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   4,6T  0 part /media/external_hdd
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  15,3G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  97,8G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 265,3G  0 part /media/partition1
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  98,1G  0 part /media/partition2
```

`rsync` transfer within the primary SSD:

```
genbatro@laptop:/media/partition2$ rsync -av --progress --remove-source-files /media/partition1/video* .
sending incremental file list
video1.mp4
  7,432,651,371 100%   67.18MB/s    0:01:45 (xfr#1, to-chk=1/2)
video2.mp4
 10,765,944,253 100%  103.07MB/s    0:01:39 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/2)

sent 18,203,038,850 bytes  received 70 bytes  87,725,488.77 bytes/sec
total size is 18,198,595,624  speedup is 1.00
```

`rsync` transfer to the external HDD:

```
genbatro@laptop:/media/partition2$ rsync -av --progress --remove-source-files video* /media/external_hdd/videos/
video1.mp4
  7,432,651,371 100%  444.66MB/s    0:00:15 (xfr#1, to-chk=1/2)
video2.mp4
 10,765,944,253 100%   93.32MB/s    0:01:50 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/2)

sent 18,203,038,826 bytes  received 70 bytes  142,768,932.52 bytes/sec
total size is 18,198,595,624  speedup is 1.00
```

Comment: How long does it take to `sync` after each of those attempts?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Good question. I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: And, just in case, what SSD model? (Plenty of SSDs are actually slower than an HDD at raw throughput, once you max out the fast write cache...)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Alright, so I transferred the files back to partition1, synced, and re-did the experiment, with `&& time sync` slapped onto the end of the commands. The results were completely different. Suddenly the internal transfer had an average of 400 MB/s all the way throughout. Maybe they were cached in memory from the last run or something, I don't know. The transfer to the external SSD was about the same as last time. `sync` times: internal: `0m30,573s`, external: `1m49,941s`. So regardless of any memory cache, I think you might be spot on with the `sync` comment. :)

Comment: Is there such a thing as "warming up" the SSD or something, that can explain why a second run is so dramatically much faster than the first run? Or is it all down to caches and buffers?

Comment: Oh, and the SSD model is a Toshiba KXG50ZNV512G, which came standard in the Dell XPS 9570 I bought in 2018.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it's more the SSD or the OS itself; if you run top/htop you'll see RAM usage divided into, among other things, "buffers" (pending to be written to disk) and "cache" (recently read)... It might be worth re-testing with a sync before (maybe also blockdev --flushbufs? but I think that's not needed when going through the filesystem), so that you're measuring only the rsync itself and not whatever happened to be pending from previous operations.

Comment: (So for writes you have 'sync' to flush from RAM to the disk, and then the SSD itself gradually flushes from its SLC cache to main flash. For reads, I don't think the SSD has any caching but there *is* sort of "pre-warming" of *reads* in system RAM – you can actually use 'fincore' or 'vmtouch -v' to see how much of a file is cached in system RAM, 'vmtouch -ve' to evict a file, or 'sysctl vm.drop_caches=3' to evict absolutely everything, forcing it to be re-read from the SSD.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity I had never heard about blockdev and fincore, so I just read up, and learned a lot. Thank you!